# Obtain information about a a position from Stockfish

Tags: engines, stockfish, programming, computer-chess, uci

I want to know from Stockfish:

1. All possible moves in a position, a.k.a. a depth 1 analysis with no score.
2. If the king is in check, is checkmated, or if there is a draw.
3. The current FEN string, after a move.

How can I get all of those? I tried looking in the [UCI specs](https://gist.github.com/aliostad/f4470274f39d29b788c1b09519e67372) and there is nothing like it.  I found some answers as to the first question, but they were all in Python. I am looking for pure UCI commands as I am using C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want to use a library/API to get this information, then you will need to implement some parsing to get it, but in principle (almost) all the info you need is available via (non-standard) UCI commands:

1. Legal moves

Perft lists all legal moves. E.g., for the starting position `go perft 1` gives you:

```
a2a3: 1
b2b3: 1
c2c3: 1
d2d3: 1
e2e3: 1
f2f3: 1
g2g3: 1
h2h3: 1
a2a4: 1
b2b4: 1
c2c4: 1
d2d4: 1
e2e4: 1
f2f4: 1
g2g4: 1
h2h4: 1
b1a3: 1
b1c3: 1
g1f3: 1
g1h3: 1

Nodes searched: 20
```

2.+3. Game state

`d` is a non-standard UCI command in Stockfish to print debug information. It contains information like the FEN and pieces giving check, e.g.,

```
position startpos moves e2e3 f7f5 d1h5
d
```

```
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 | r | n | b | q | k | b | n | r | 8
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 | p | p | p | p | p |   | p | p | 7
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 6
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 |   |   |   |   |   | p |   | Q | 5
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 4
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 |   |   |   |   | P |   |   |   | 3
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 | P | P | P | P |   | P | P | P | 2
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 | R | N | B |   | K | B | N | R | 1
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h

Fen: rnbqkbnr/ppppp1pp/8/5p1Q/8/4P3/PPPP1PPP/RNB1KBNR b KQkq - 1 2
Key: 47C539B3DEE3D29B
Checkers: h5
```

In order to determine whether it is checkmate, you need to check whether perft 1 is zero and checkers from `d` is non-empty.

For draw detection I think there is no straightforward way to do it with plain Stockfish. The only draw that can safely be detected is stalemate, similar to the checkmate detection mentioned above.

Comment: and if I do not mind to use some API / library,  what would you recommend for c#?

Comment: I do not have any experience with C#, but https://github.com/search?l=C%23&q=chess&type=Repositories seems to suggest some options like https://github.com/thomas-daniels/Chess.NET or https://github.com/rudzen/ChessLib.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know it is out of context, but I dont want to spam the site with any more questions. What uci command should I use to get the list of all possible moves + their rank (as in d2 d4 = 1.2, d2 d3 = -0.5 etc...) currently when you use the go command you only get the best move, but I need all of them + ranking

Comment: multiPV https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish#multipv is perhaps what your are looking for